# Python program and datetime Localization

Tags: python, datetime, localization

I did a little Python program :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
""" Program that ask for the birth date and return the day name of the birth """

from datetime import datetime

def ask_birthdate():
    """ Raw input of the birth date """
    date = raw_input("Enter your birth date (DD-MM-YYYY) : ").strip()
    return datetime.strptime(date, '%d-%m-%Y')

def birthday(date):
    """ Localized day of birth """
    return date.strftime('%A')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    date = ask_birthdate()
    print u"You was born a %s" % birthday(date)
```

It is quite simple, but I would like to translate it.
First there is the IHM text (Enter your birth date) and (You was born a) then I also wish to translate the name of the day.

In the doc, I saw that it should be localized, but how should I configure the program to be localized ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [Locale Module](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html).

simply add the following lines to your code:

```
import locale

... 

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '<desired local>')
# NOTE: using locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '') will use the machine's default locale defined in the LANG environment variable.
```

I set the 'desired local' to 'de_DE' and it produced the following using your code:

```
Enter your birth date (DD-MM-YYYY) : 15-08-2012
You was born a Mittwoch
```

Comment: And if you want to specify the '<desired local>' you have to choose one from your system locales : `locale -a`